# How to remove Controller and method URL in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, codeigniter-2

This is my current URL `http://www.example.com/agent/index/$id`,
and I want to change this `http://www.example.com/demo_name(by agent name)`
Please suggest your answer.

Comment: See: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand. But if you want omit the "index" in the url. You need to use a .htaccess file. This is a example:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|assets|robots.txt) 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /directory/index.php/$1 [L]
```